# WPF - How to write a trigger for mouse over of grid?

Tags: wpf, triggers

I see that Button object has a IsMouseOVer property.

But how do create an effect for the mouse over of a grid or other
element that does not have IsMouseOver??

Thanks
Malcolm

Edit: i figured it out. I was using the wrong method for setting the trigger.

Comment: I am wondering what the correct method is, in case I run into the same problem later.:)

Answer (score 55):

I realize that I am responding to a dead thread but since I came across it, and since the thread is not answered, I am going to answer it.

The [WPF Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) has an "IsMouseOver" property.

I think this question was asked because the "IsMouseOver" property only changes if the mouse is over a "hit-testable" control (ie a Button, or ComboBox) within the Grid itself.

Therefore, it may appear that the "IsMouseOver" property doesn't work (especially if you are using it in a trigger to set the Grid's Visible property).

For example:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  
  <Button Grid.Column="1">A Button</Button>

  <Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

The above Grid and it's contents will be displayed in half opacity.
You will notice that the opacity will *not* be set to full if you hover over the first column (which doesn't contain anything); however the opacity *will* be set to full if you hover over the button in the second column. This is because the first column, with nothing in it, is not hit-testable; whereas, the button within the second column is hit-testable and so the event is triggered.

If you want the Grid's IsMouseOver property to detect when the mouse is anywhere over the Grid itself all you have to do is set the Background property of the Grid to something that is not Null (set it to Transparent for example). Setting the Background property will make the Grid "hit-testable".

The following code will fix the problem:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  
  <Button Grid.Column="1">A Button</Button>

  <Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

-Frinny

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out. I couldn't understand why the Grid wasn't responding to the _MouseEnter_ event.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. This problem stumped me for a while too (mainly because I didn't know about the hit testable concept at the time)

Answer (score 4):

One can also use the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events as such:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,0,-300,0" To="0,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,0,0,0" To="0,0,-300,0" AccelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the "MouseEnter" and "MouseLeave" actions on the WPF object.

Comment: There are no "MouseEnter" and "MouseLeave" Properties on WPF objects; however there are "MouseEnter" and "MouseLeave" Events for WPF objects. The WPF Grid has an "IsMouseOver" Property that you can use in a style trigger for the Grid. The catch is that the mouse has to be over a control within the Grid for the IsMouseOver Property to change...